# Increasing Progress Percent during downloading in ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, progress

I am making a list view downloader using AsyncTask. I want to show the progress bar percentage on my listview during downloading but my percentage is not increasing.I know hoe to show the percentage in Progress Dialog but i dont know how to update in List View. Here is my code:

**FileDownloadTask.java**

```
public class FileDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private static final String    TAG = FileDownloadTask.class.getSimpleName();
    final DownloadInfo  mInfo;
    public int progress;

    public FileDownloadTask(DownloadInfo info) {
        mInfo = info;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        mInfo.setProgress(values[0]);
        mInfo.setFilePercent(values[0]);
        ProgressBar bar = mInfo.getProgressBar();

        if(bar != null) {
            bar.setProgress(mInfo.getProgress());

        }

    }

     @Override

     protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
         int count;
         try {
             String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

             System.out.println("Downloading");
             URL url = new URL(mInfo.getFileUrl());

             URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
             conection.connect();
             // getting file length
             int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

             // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer

             // Output stream to write file
             File rootdirectory= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),"Youtube Videos");
              if(!rootdirectory.exists())
              {
                  rootdirectory.mkdirs();
              }
             String nameoffile= URLUtil.guessFileName(mInfo.getFileUrl(),null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(mInfo.getFileUrl()));
             File file= new File(rootdirectory,nameoffile);
             file.createNewFile();



             mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.DOWNLOADING);
             InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

             OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
             byte data[] = new byte[1024];

             long total = 0;
             while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                 total += count;
                 progress= (int)((total*1001)/lenghtOfFile);
               publishProgress(progress);

                 mInfo.setFilePercent(progress);

                 // writing data to file
                 output.write(data, 0, count);

             }

             // flushing output
             output.flush();

             // closing streams
             output.close();
             input.close();

         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
         }
         mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.COMPLETE);
         return null;
     }






    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.COMPLETE);
      //  String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.mp4";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.DOWNLOADING);
    }


}
```

**DownloadInfoArrayAdapter.Java**

```
public class DownloadInfoArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DownloadInfo> {
    // Simple class to make it so that we don't have to call findViewById frequently

    public static Integer result;
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        Button button;
        DownloadInfo info;
        TextView size;
        TextView prog;
    }


    private static final String TAG = DownloadInfoArrayAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public DownloadInfoArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                    List<DownloadInfo> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        final DownloadInfo info = getItem(position);
       // SignInAsyntask task1 = new SignInAsyntask(info);
        //task1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        //new SignInAsyntask().execute();
        // We need to set the convertView's progressBar to null.

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(null == row) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_download_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadFileName);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
            holder.size=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadFileSize);
            holder.prog=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadFileProgress);
            holder.button = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
            holder.info = info;

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

            holder.info.setProgressBar(null);
            holder.info = info;
            holder.info.setProgressBar(holder.progressBar);
            holder.info.setProgress(null);
            holder.info = info;
           // holder.info.setProgress(holder.prog);
        }

        holder.textView.setText(info.getFilename());
        holder.progressBar.setProgress(info.getProgress());
        holder.progressBar.setMax(info.getFileSize());
        holder.prog.setText(info.getFilePercent() + "/100");
        holder.size.setText(info.getFileSize() + "MB");

        info.setProgressBar(holder.progressBar);
        //info.setProgress(holder.prog);

        holder.button.setEnabled(info.getDownloadState() == DownloadState.NOT_STARTED);
        final Button button = holder.button;
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                info.setDownloadState(DownloadState.QUEUED);
                button.setEnabled(false);
                button.invalidate();
                FileDownloadTask task = new FileDownloadTask(info);
                task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            }
        });


        //TODO: When reusing a view, invalidate the current progressBar.

        return row;
    }
}
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constructor try to pass data through doInbackground parameter

```
FileDownloadTask task = new FileDownloadTask().execute(DownloadInfo info);

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(DownloadInfo... params) {
   info = params[0];
..

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick: don't try to set anything on the View directly. Instead, change the data, call notifyDataSetChanged() on the ArrayAdapter, and allow it to change the Views. For example,

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    mInfo.setProgress(values[0]);
    mInfo.setFilePercent(values[0]);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Where adapter should either be the instance of your Adapter, or a callback to the Adapter's Activity which will then relay the updated message to the  Adapter, which with then call your overridden getView(int, View, Viewgroup) method and correctly show the updated data (I'm a fan of the latter).

(This is also assuming your mInfo instance is the same instance backed by your Adapter, of course.)

Edit: Just a post-thought: you may also want to make sure only a single instance of your downloader for an item is running at a time, as currently yours would start multiple different downloaders if you keep clicking, which would probably cause some issues for you. Cheers~

Comment: whenever i write adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onProgressUpdate or doinBackground(), the app crashes.

Comment: With what kind of error? If it's a NullPointerException, it's likely either the reference to your adapter is null, or something is wrong in the adapter's overridden getView() method